# how to make variable depend on radio button binded value

Tags: angular, data-binding

I would like to have a boolean variable that depends on the mgModel (enum) value of a radio button.
See my code:

the enum:

```
export enum advancedSearchMap_SigningTools
{
  none,
  radius1, 
  radius2, 
  radius3, 
  radius4
}
```

The html

```
<div class="markerFiled BtnChangeMark">
              <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="m1" value="localAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools.radius1" [(ngModel)]="selectedAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools" >
                <span>...</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="markerFiled BtnChangeSearch">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="m1" value="localAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools.radius2" [(ngModel)]="selectedAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools">
                <span>...</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="markerFiled BtnChangeSearch">
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="m1" value="localAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools.radius3" [(ngModel)]="selectedAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools">
                  <span>...</span>
              </label>
            </div>
```

and the variable is:

```
selectedAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools : advancedSearchMap_SigningTools = 
advancedSearchMap_SigningTools.none;
```

The isSigningToolSelected value stays false. What should I do to make it updated according to the radio button value (I don't want to add click event to every radio button)

Answer (score 0):

OK - Fixed it: I made the variable a property:

```
get isSigningToolSelected()
{
   return this.selectedAdvancedSearchMap_SigningTools != 
    advancedSearchMap_SigningTools.none;
}
```